# Using python scrapy to scrape the next page comments

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I am using python scrapy to get the user Reviews comments, which may have multiple pages and I need to click "see more " so as to see more comments.

this is the link to the page I want to crawl:
https://en.drivy.com/car-rental/berlin/dacia-dokker-218119

I notice if the review comments more than 10, I need to click "See more" link in order to get the subsequent comments.
I also notice the "see more" URL link is https: //en.drivy.com/cars/218119/reviews?page=2&rel=next

However, if I use scrapy to go to the https: //en.drivy.com/cars/218119/reviews?page=2&rel=next, the website redirects me back to  https:// en.drivy.com/car-rental/berlin/dacia-dokker-218119  which i cant really get the next ten comments. (i wonder if the website use cookie or session ID and identify my scrapy as new visit)

I know I can use python selenium to open the web page and click "see more" so as to get the comments, however, selenium is very slow and I wish I can use scrapy instead.

Could anyone help me on this? or at least give me a direction to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `"Accept: */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"` header. You'll catch JS object containing texts of comments.

`yield Request("https://en.drivy.com/cars/218119/reviews?page=2&rel=next", parse = ..., ...,
headers={'Accept': "*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"})`

Comment: thank you for the reply. I tried by setting the header as showed by you.
however, i receive this error

2017-10-10 16:24:45 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://en.drivy.com/cars/218119/reviews?page=2&rel=next> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Have you included other headers (especially X-CSRF-Token)?